# How to construct 5x5 matrix to apply as color matrix in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, matrix, cifilter, brightness

I need some help again converting my Android app to iOS...

As I mentioned in other post the app is about image processing and it's based on ColorMatrix. The problem is that Swift only supports (as far as I know...) 4x4 matrix and for brightness or contrast I use 5x5 matrix in Android.

In Android these are my matrix:

Brightness:

```
float[] brightMatrix = {
                1f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 32f,
                0f, 1f, 0f, 0f, 32f,
                0f, 0f, 1f, 0f, 32f,
                0f, 0f, 0f, 1f,  0f,
                0f, 0f, 0f, 0f,  1f};
```

Contrast:

```
float[] contMatrix = {
                1.190f,     0f,     0f, 0f, -12.065f,
                    0f, 1.190f,     0f, 0f, -12.065f,
                    0f,     0f, 1.190f, 0f, -12.065f,
                    0f,     0f,     0f, 1f,       0f,
                    0f,     0f,     0f, 0f,       1f};
```

But I really don't know how to get same results in Swift...

In case of Brightness I've tried to use this code dividing 32/255 to get the value 0.12549:

```
func zoeFilter() -> UIImage? {
   let inImage = CIImage (image: self)
   dynamic let brightFactor = CIFilter (name: "CIColorControls")
   brightFactor?.setValue(inImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
   brightFactor?.setValue(0.12549, forKey: kCIInputBrightnessKey)
   let brightImage = brightFactor?.outputImage
   let cgImage = CIContext().createCGImage(brightImage!, from: brightImage!.extent)
   return UIImage (cgImage: cgImage!)
}
```

But the result is not the same at all... in iOS it's like a white fog...

And speaking about Contrast I've found the next code but it's impossible for me to transform the Android matrix in just a value here `contFactor?.setValue(1, forKey: kCIInputContrastKey)` just knowing that 1 is equal to neutral:

```
func chiaFilter() -> UIImage? {
   let inImage = CIImage (image: self)
   dynamic let contFactor = CIFilter (name: "CIColorControls")
   contFactor?.setValue(inImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
   contFactor?.setValue(1, forKey: kCIInputContrastKey)
   let contImage = contFactor?.outputImage
   let cgImage = CIContext().createCGImage(contImage!, from: contImage!.extent)
   return UIImage (cgImage: cgImage!)
}
```

On the other side, changing the exposure is easy because the matrix in Android is like:

```
float[] expMatrix = {
                1.3f,   0f,   0f, 0f, 0f,
                  0f, 1.3f,   0f, 0f, 0f,
                  0f,   0f, 1.3f, 0f, 0f,
                  0f,   0f,   0f, 1f, 0f,
                  0f,   0f,   0f, 0f, 1f};
```

So in Swift I can use the next code getting exactly the same result:

```
func liaFilter() -> UIImage? {
   let inImage = CIImage (image: self)
   dynamic let expoMatrix = CIFilter (name: "CIColorMatrix")
   expoMatrix?.setDefaults()
   expoMatrix?.setValue(inImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
   expoMatrix?.setValue(CIVector (x: 1.3, y: 0, z: 0, w: 0), forKey: "inputRVector")
   expoMatrix?.setValue(CIVector (x: 0, y: 1.3, z: 0, w: 0), forKey: "inputGVector")
   expoMatrix?.setValue(CIVector (x: 0, y: 0, z: 1.3, w: 0), forKey: "inputBVector")
   expoMatrix?.setValue(CIVector (x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, w: 1), forKey: "inputAVector")
   let expoImage = expoMatrix?.outputImage
   let cgImage = CIContext().createCGImage(expoImage!, from: expoImage!.extent)
   return UIImage (cgImage: cgImage!)
}
```

It's so confused... I know... but it'd be great if someone could have an idea about how to solve these problems between Android and iOS.

Thanks in advance!

***EDITION AFTER FRANK'S ANSWER***

Here is the original image:
[image]

Here is after applying filter with Android using:

```
float[] brightMatrix = {
                1f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 32f,
                0f, 1f, 0f, 0f, 32f,
                0f, 0f, 1f, 0f, 32f,
                0f, 0f, 0f, 1f,  0f,
                0f, 0f, 0f, 0f,  1f};
```

[image]

Here is the same picture applying filter with iOS using:

```
brightMatrix?.setValue(CIVector (x: 1, y: 0, z: 0, w: 0), forKey: "inputRVector")
brightMatrix?.setValue(CIVector (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0, w: 0), forKey: "inputGVector")
brightMatrix?.setValue(CIVector (x: 0, y: 0, z: 1, w: 0), forKey: "inputBVector")
brightMatrix?.setValue(CIVector (x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, w: 1), forKey: "inputAVector")
brightMatrix?.setValue(CIVector (x: 32.0/255.0, y: 32.0/255.0, z: 32.0/255.0, w: 0), forKey: "inputBiasVector")
```

[image]

***FINAL SOLUTION WORKING AFTER FRANK'S PROPOSAL***

```
func zoeFilter() -> UIImage? {
        let inImage = CIImage (image: self)

        dynamic let SRGBMatrix = CIFilter (name: "CILinearToSRGBToneCurve")
        dynamic let brightMatrix = CIFilter (name: "CIColorMatrix")
        dynamic let linearMatrix = CIFilter (name: "CISRGBToneCurveToLinear")

        SRGBMatrix?.setValue(inImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        let SRGBImage = SRGBMatrix?.outputImage

        brightMatrix?.setDefaults()
        brightMatrix?.setValue(SRGBImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        brightMatrix?.setValue(CIVector (x: 1, y: 0, z: 0, w: 0), forKey: "inputRVector")
        brightMatrix?.setValue(CIVector (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0, w: 0), forKey: "inputGVector")
        brightMatrix?.setValue(CIVector (x: 0, y: 0, z: 1, w: 0), forKey: "inputBVector")
        brightMatrix?.setValue(CIVector (x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, w: 1), forKey: "inputAVector")
        brightMatrix?.setValue(CIVector (x: 32.0/255.0, y: 32.0/255.0, z: 32.0/255.0, w: 0), forKey: "inputBiasVector")
        let brightImage = brightMatrix?.outputImage

        linearMatrix?.setDefaults()
        linearMatrix?.setValue(brightImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        let linearImage = linearMatrix?.outputImage

        let cgImage = CIContext().createCGImage(linearImage!, from: linearImage!.extent)
        return UIImage (cgImage: cgImage!)
    }
```

Comment: Glad it worked! Two additions: (1) You don't need to `setDefaults` on the filters if you set all parameters anyway (or the filter doesn't have any). (2) You can use the shortcut `let SRGBImage = inImage.applyingFilter("CILinearToSRGBToneCurve")` to save a few lines each.

Comment: I'll take these tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use your brightness and contrast matrices by also setting the `inputBiasVector` parameter of the `CIColorMatrix` filter like so:

```
// the first 4 should actually be the default, so you probably don't need to set them explicitly
brightMatrix?.setValue(CIVector(x: 1, y: 0, z: 0, w: 0), forKey: "inputRVector")
brightMatrix?.setValue(CIVector(x: 0, y: 1, z: 0, w: 0), forKey: "inputGVector")
brightMatrix?.setValue(CIVector(x: 0, y: 0, z: 1, w: 0), forKey: "inputBVector")
brightMatrix?.setValue(CIVector(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, w: 1), forKey: "inputAVector")
brightMatrix?.setValue(CIVector(x: 32.0/255.0, y: 32.0/255.0, z: 32.0/255.0, w: 0), forKey: "inputBiasVector")
```

It's strange, though, that you can't use the `CIColorControls` filter to achieve the same. Maybe you can post example images.

Comment: Thanks Frank for your answer! Good to know about the Bias Vector although the result is the same than using CIColorControl... I added some pictures.

Comment: This might be an issue caused by gamma correction (or the lack thereof). It seems your Android filter is operating on an sRGB gamma curve whereas Core Image usually uses a linear distribution. Maybe you could try to add a `CILinearToSRGBToneCurve` filter to your pipeline right before the color matrix and a `CISRGBToneCurveToLinear` afterward (or the other way around, I'm not sure...).

Comment: Man, you’re a genius! Thank you so much because it was the key... Tomorrow I post the final code which is working based on your help. Thanks again!

Comment: Final code added as solution! Thank you again, Frank!

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same problem, but thanks to @Tsilaicos and @Frank I have my solution.

But the filter chaining way in the final solution is inefficient. Apple Documentation [indicates](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/ciimage/2915368-imagebyapplyingfilter?language=objc) "**This method, though convenient, is inefficient if used multiple times in succession. Achieve better performance by chaining filters without asking for the outputs of individual filters.**"

Instead of using output images directly, we should pass them as arguments to the next filters. Here is the efficient way, which is about 20 times faster than the original one:

```swift
let image = UIImage(named: "example.jpg")!
let ciImage = CIImage(image: image)

let matrix = [
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 30,
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 30,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 30,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0
]

let linearToSRGBFilter = CIFilter(
    name: "CILinearToSRGBToneCurve",
    parameters: [
        kCIInputImageKey: ciImage
    ]
)

let mainFilter = CIFilter(
    name: "CIColorMatrix",
    parameters: [
        kCIInputImageKey: linearToSRGBFilter!.outputImage!,
        "inputRVector": CIVector(x: matrix[0], y: matrix[1], z: matrix[2], w: matrix[3]),
        "inputGVector": CIVector(x: matrix[5], y: matrix[6], z: matrix[7], w: matrix[8]),
        "inputBVector": CIVector(x: matrix[10], y: matrix[11], z: matrix[12], w: matrix[13]),
        "inputAVector": CIVector(x: matrix[15], y: matrix[16], z: matrix[17], w: matrix[18]),
        "inputBiasVector": CIVector(x: matrix[4] / 256, y: matrix[9] / 256, z: matrix[14] / 256, w: matrix[19] / 256)
    ]
)

let srgbToLinearFilter = CIFilter(
    name: "CISRGBToneCurveToLinear",
    parameters: [
        kCIInputImageKey: mainFilter!.outputImage!
    ]
)

let outputCIImage = srgbToLinearFilter?.outputImage
let outputCGImage = CIContext().createCGImage(outputCIImage!, from: outputCIImage!.extent)!
let outputImage = UIImage(cgImage: outputCGImage)
```

For a 2 MB image file, the elapsed time is ~0.1 seconds on my machine. It was taking more than 2 seconds with the original way.

Note: You should do the filter operations in a background thread. (e.g. `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { ... }`)